# Defining Numerical Values in Racket

Tags: variables, racket

Forgive me, I am just starting Racket, so this question may be very simple to answer. I am trying to design a function that when given an integer that represents distance in miles will return the time (in hours) it takes to travel that distance when going 60 MPH. I know basic python, so I am familiar with programming.. But I do not know how to set this type of function up in Racket.

Answer (score 3):

First have to declare the function with a parameter, like this:

```
(define (calculate-time distance)
  ...)
```

And then, perform the actual calculation. Remember, in Scheme we use prefix notation:

```
(define (calculate-time distance)
  (/ distance 60.0))
```

For example, to cover a distance of 600 miles, it'll take 10 hours:

```
(calculate-time 600)
=> 10.0
```

Comment: In such a simple, getting-started example, I wonder if It might be good to use `60.0`? To postpone explaining results like `(calculate-time 121) => 121/60` or talking about `exact->inexact`?

Comment: @GregHendershott that's a sound suggestion, for simplicity's sake. Thanks, I updated my answer accordingly